# При регистрации проверить существует ли логин в файле .json

Tags: php, json

Всем привет. Cоздаю веб-приложение авторизации и регистрации с использованием jsondb.
Вот исполняемый файл:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    require_once 'jsondb/JsonDb.php';

use JsonDb\JsonDb\JsonDb;
$optisons = [
    'compress_mode' => false,
];

$DB = new JsonDb($optisons);

$DB->table('users')->autoIncremeIntAdd('id');

$login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $error_fields = [];

    if ($login === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'login';
    }

    if ($pass === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'pass';
    }

    if ($password_confirm === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'password_confirm';
    }

    if ($email === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'email';
    }

    if ($username === '') {
        $error_fields[] = 'username';
    }

    if (!empty($error_fields)) {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Проверьте правильность заполнения полей",
            "fields" => $error_fields
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }

  if (mb_strlen($login) < 6)
    {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Недопустимая длина логина",
            "fields" => ['login']
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }
    
    if (!preg_match("/^(?=.*[a-zа-я])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\d]{6,}$/",$pass))
    {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Пароль должен состоять из букв и цифр и быть длиной не менее 6 символов",
            "fields" => ['pass']
        ];
        echo json_encode($response); 
        die();      
    }

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Неправильно введен email",
            "fields" => ['email']
        ];
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    } 

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]{2,}$/",$username))
    {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Имя может состоять только из двух букв",
            "fields" => ['username']
        ];
        echo json_encode($response); 
        die();
    }

    if ($pass === $password_confirm) 
    {
        $pass = md5($pass);

        $DB->table('users')->insert(
            [
                'login' => $login,
                'pass' => $pass,
                'email' => $email,
                'username' => $username
            ]   
        );

       $response = [
           "status" => true, 
       ];
       echo json_encode($response);

    } else 
    {
       $response = [
           "status" => false,
           "message" => "Пароли не совпадают",
       ];
       echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Идет проверка валидности полей, и если все окей данные заносятся в файл users.json. Есть код , где использовалось подключение к бд phpMyAdmin и соответственно пользовалась языком mysql:

```
    $check_login = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_login) > 0) {
        $response = [
            "status" => false,
            "type" => 1,
            "message" => "Такой логин уже существует",
            "fields" => ['login'],
        ];

        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }
```

И вот как сделать тоже самое но с проверкой из файла, может кто-то работал с jsondb?

Comment: Из какого файла? Поясните.

Comment: Данные из формы регистрации заносятся в файл users.json. Из него сделать проверку на существование логина при авторизации.